# How to compare to BigInteger values?

Tags: mysql

I have a list of BigInteger value in two separate tables, say t1 and t2. They are inserted as longtext data type using MySQL Workbench. I want to check each value in t1 if it exists in t2. I executed the following statement:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    t1
WHERE   col1.t1 IN
   (
     SELECT col1.t2 
     FROM   t2
   ) ;
```

But statement seems will never ends (hundreds of thousands records). Now I want to re insert the numbers as BIGINT as comparing numbers will be faster than text. I read these BigInteger values line by line from a text file using Java program. The program gives me the following error:

> DB_Error:_com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of
>   range value for column

How can I solve this problem? I need to compare BigInteger vales as fast as possible.

Comment: Do you have the table definitions of your 2 tables ? Do you have the code that parses and inserts the data ? Can you print out the exact value you are trying to insert when this happens ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try

```
    SELECT t1.* FROM t1,t2 WHERE t1.col1=t2.col2;
```

this would be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

In your first attempt try to create index for text columns t1.col1 and t2.col1. Then use this query:

```
select distinct t1.col1 from t1 join t2 on (t1.col1=t2.col1)
```